# ChangePivotCache giving type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a macro that previously reset the cache of two pivot tables without any error. I'm running into a run time error 13 type mismatch for just 1 of the tables and I do not understand why it's suddenly not working. And for just the one table as well when the code is identical for both tables.

```
Sub refresh_caches()

Dim cpt As PivotTable, chpt As PivotTable
Set ca2 = Sheets("claim edit").Range("A2")
Set cha2 = Sheets("chrg review").Range("A2")
Set cpc = Range(ca2.End(xlToRight), ca2.End(xlDown))
Set chpc = Range(cha2.End(xlToRight), cha2.End(xlDown))
Set cpt = Sheets("Formulas & Pivots").PivotTables("ptClaim")
Set chpt = Sheets("Formulas & Pivots").PivotTables("ptCharge")


cpt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        cpc, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

chpt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        chpc, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

For Each PivotCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    PivotCache.Refresh
    Next
End Sub
```

The run time error is hitting on the `changepivotcache` code. When I step through and skip to the second code for `chpt`, it updates that table fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** The error appears after the data source, which is a data connection, is refreshed. I get the same error even when referencing the range directly as the `sourcedata`. Though if i manually change the data source the pivot table updates just fine.

Whats also odd that when referencing the full range of data directly it will throw the error, but if I do not reference every row it will update the table.

**NEW Edit** I believe I've identified the line causing my issue, though I do not fully understand why or if this is what caused the issue previously. I narrowed the issue down to the exact cell and it seems to happen whenever any cell in the range contains more than 255 characters. I tested this with additional cells in the range by adding text to the cell and prompted the error, likewise I could prevent the error by ensuring the text of the cell contained no more than 255 chars.

Why is this? I can manually select the data range and use it as my pivotcache but I cannot get the code to do the exact same thing. Found some issues with cells exceeding 255 chars on google but am still baffled as I'm not referencing the cell specifically, just including it in a range. Would really appreciate some insight on this, especially so I can find a workaround for the next time the data pulls a cell value exceeding this limit.

Comment: What the error say. Runtime for ?

Comment: the error is Type Mismatch.

Comment: Select/Active that table and use `ActiveTable.Change....` to see if you get the same error.

Comment: It seems to have no issue running the script until I refresh the data connection which is the source for the pivot cache.

Comment: That's a test. Not a solution.

Comment: still run-time error '13': Type mismatch.   Above I noted it seems to happen after the data connection is refreshed.

Comment: Still baffled, but updated my weekly dashboard yesterday without any issue so I guess all set?

Comment: Did you apply any changes? if yes, keep us posted. Maybe that'd help someone. If not, then what happened exactly? Updating your ms office or anything?

Comment: Issue has resurfaced. The only trend I have been able to notice is that this has occurred upon someone else trying to update the dashboard in my absence. Will do some digging to see if I can identify any conflicting data with this file and the previous version.

Comment: Updated OP after identifying issue (see above), though I am still uncertain why this would cause the type mismatch error. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/542927/increase-size-limit-of-data-import-from-csv-into-excel

Comment: https://www.iditect.com/faq/excel/exception-the-total-length-of-a-datavalidation-list-cannot-exceed-255-characters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still do not fully understand why the code errors out whenever a cell containing over 255 characters are included in the data range, it does appear to be the cause.

I've implemented a bit of code to simply identify the cells and reduce the text down to the acceptable amount before setting the `PivotCache`.

```
Dim c as Range
For each c in Range("SpecialtyClaimEdit") 'the name of my data connection
 If Len(c) > 255 Then
 c = Left(c, 255)
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that excel has a limit of 255 characters for some properties for some reason.

For instance, I was trying to set descriptions for my UDFs (user-defined functions) and I found out that it is limited to 255 characters. Here's my question: [Error while setting UDF description in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072840/error-while-setting-udf-description-in-vba)

Also, if you try to write a function with more than 255 characters in one cell excel cannot handle it. Look at this thread: [Excel: Use formula longer that 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386414/excel-use-formula-longer-that-255-characters)

What you have now as an answer works but also you need to loop over all of the cells and loose/remove some of the data. I think, it may also work to make a new sheet and refer to the cells in your original sheet (e.g in cell `A1` of the new sheet you type `='Formulas & Pivots'!A1`). Then, use that sheet in your code. You need to take the address of the pivot table range from the original sheet and then set another range which is the same but in the new sheet.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. Using the second sheet to pull in a cell value exceeding 255 chars with the formula will not prompt the error because the actual value of the cell is only 23 characters long?

Comment: @Awill Right, that's the idea.

Comment: That's a clever workaround, though in my case I'm setting the `PivotCache` as an ever changing data source. The long text that I have isn't pertinent information so cutting it short or replacing it may be a quicker solution. I'm not expecting to run into many of these either, I hope.