# VBA Type mismatch error in one workbook but not two others

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm working on a macro to take raw exports of timesheet data and plop a couple pivot tables on it.

Right now I have three different exports to choose from, all are simple .xls dumps from the system and contain the same data formatted in the same manner. I re-save them as .xlsx and then run the macro.

My problem is that the macro works perfectly for the first two books, but encounters *"Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"* on the third. Specifically, the debugger points to the second line below (where I create the pivot cache):

```
Set PivotSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hours by Person")
Set PivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange)
Set PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(PivotSheet.Cells(1, 1), "HoursByPersonTable")
PivotSheet.Activate
```

I've run it through line by line a couple times now in the debugger and my local variables all look fine. There is no functional difference between the three files that I'm working with so I'm at a loss.

[Here is the full macro code.](https://gist.github.com/Lmaster20/779343c59b3bb8fba2abf4f3fcdc3278)

Comment: Verify the contents of `DataRange` in the 3rd workbook. What's different than in the other two books? Any worksheet errors?

Comment: Also, why delete & re-create the whole thing, instead of just modifying the source data and refreshing the pivot?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I cannot find any difference in the DataRange between the three files. There are no errors. The three sheets get deleted at the start because for the purpose of keeping things clean while I worked on the macro. Creating a pivot table manually works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally I didn't find this until *after* I'd already posted, but [credit to Awill for coming up with a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141927/changepivotcache-giving-type-mismatch-error?rq=1)

I don't understand it any better than they do, but after searching my DataRange I found a single cell with more than 255 chars in it. Trimmed that down to 255 and the macro works again.